# Is Douglas Station and Earth's Spacedock the same station?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-lower-decks

In *Star Trek: Lower Decks* season 3 finale "The Stars at Night", the Cerritos is at Douglas Station (again) and Captain Freeman is at Starfleet Headquarters in San Fransisco. Given the plot, it would make sense that Douglas Station and Earth's Spacedock are one and the same. Are they? Memory Alpha still treats them as different but uses "Spacedock-type".

> Given the plot of "The Stars at Night" that Douglas Station is heavily damaged *and* the Earth Spacedock is supposedly all new in Season 3 of *Star Trek: Picard*, I was personally hoping LD would actually go all the way in destroying Douglas Station to tie the series together.

Answer (score 6):

We see [Douglas Station](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Douglas_Station) in *Lower Decks: Second Contact*. That ain't Earth under it.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some arguments why the planet in the picture can't be Earth? It isn't very hard to imagine that it is a slightly different take on [this shot](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Spacedock_(Earth)?file=Earth_Spacedock%252C_2293.jpg) (with less detalization because cartoon).

Comment: It doesn't look like Earth and Earth isn't that colour

Comment: Such a simple and powerful, as well as--with all due respect--crass answer.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - /s is my basic setting